# Не работает http_build_query

Tags: php, yandex-speechkit

Вот код:

```
<?
$dir = scandir("str/");
$cd = count($dir);
for($i = 2; $i < $cd; $i++){
    $str = file_get_contents("str/".$dir[$i]);
    #echo file_get_contents("str/".$dir[$i]);
    #echo "https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?format=mp3&lang=ru-RU&speaker=jane&key=1f13aeaa-2cfc-4a5c-a79c-e14748345975&emotion=good&text=".$str."</br>";
    $qs = http_build_query(array("format" => "mp3","lang" => "ru-RU","speaker" => "jane","key" => "1f13aeaa-2cfc-4a5c-a79c-e14748345975","emotion" => "good", "text" => $str)); // параметры запроса
    $ctx = stream_context_create(array("http"=>array("method"=>"GET","header"=>"Referer: \r\n")));
    #$soundfile = file_get_contents("https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?".$qs, false, $ctx); // запрос на генерацию mp3 файла
    echo "https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?".$qs."</br>";
    #file_put_contents("text/".$i.".mp3", $soundfile);
    if($i == 11){
        break;
    }
}

?>
```

Одна из строчек вывода:

```
https://tts.voicetech.yandex.net/generate?format=mp3&lang=ru-RU&speaker=jane&key=1f13aeaa-2cfc-4a5c-a79c-e14748345975&emotion=good&text=%CA%EE%ED%E5%F6+%D1%EB%E5%EF%EE%E3%EE
```

Яндекс SpechKit не понимает и выдаёт пустоту. Как исправить чтобы был текст вместо `%CA%EE%ED%E5%F6+%D1%EB%E5%EF%EE%E3%EE`?

Comment: Скорее всего, кодировка не та. Попробуйте в utf8.